# What is wrong with my connection string?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my shared-hosted database.

They gave me this as an example:

```
Data Source=KezBlu.db.10971085.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=KezBlu; User ID=KezBlu; Password='your password';
```

From which I made:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LibKezberProjectManager.Properties.Settings.KezberPMDBConnectionString" connectionString=" Server=****.db.10971085.hostedresource.com; Database=KezBlu; User ID=****; Password=mypassword; Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But Linq cannot seem to connect to it.

I am not sure what could be wrong.

It works fine when I use my local SQLExpress...

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to replace the server, database, user ID, password, and trusted_connection with values appropriate for your database.

Comment: What on earth does "cannot seem to connect to it" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Have you tried connecting from Management Studio instead of Linq? Have you taked to GoDaddy support? Perhaps they need to allow your IP address through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the same keywords as the example given to you by the provider.

So replace `Server` with `Data Source` and `Database` with `Initial Catalog`.

You may also want to remove `Trusted_Connection=False`.

Comment: I am using vs 2012 and .net 4 too.

Comment: Do you know what version of SQL Server the host is running? You may want to have a look at [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com) to find the correct version for comparison.

Comment: Could it be because it has to be running from their server?

Comment: Yes, the server may be configured to only handle connections from within its own domain or specific machines.

Answer (score 0):

For web.config it should be like below:

```
<add name="KezberPMDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=KezBlu.db.10971085.hostedresource.com;Initial Catalog=KezBlu;User ID=KezBlu;Password=yourpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And in to code, access above connection string using following:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KezberPMDBConnectionString"].ToString());
```

**Please mark this answer useful if this solve your problem.**